# Gauss's Law for a Uniformly Charged Solid Sphere

Tags: electrostatics, symmetry, electric-fields, gauss-law

[image]

We want to calculate $\vec{E}$ at a distance $r$ from the center $O$ of a spherical polar coordinate system.

Let the point on the Gaussian surface at which we want to calculate $\vec{E}$ is $P=P(r, \theta, \phi)$.

Applying Gauss's Law we get,
$$
\oint_s \vec{E}(r, \theta, \phi) \cdot \hat{n}(r, \theta, \phi) \, ds = \oint_s E(r, \theta, \phi)\, ds = \iiint E(r, \theta, \phi)\, r^2 \sin\theta \, d\theta \, d\phi = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}.$$

At this stage how do I know that $E$ depends only on $r$; i.e., $E=E(r)$?

**Is it possible to give a mathematical proof that $E=E(r)$?**

Comment: Eventually the problem is solved. The following answers are useful and also so this: http://physnet.org/modules/pdf_modules/m153.pdf

Comment: I believe you are really just looking for this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53734/how-do-we-make-symmetry-assumptions-rigorous/53779#53779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying [Gauss' Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law) one gets (the surface integral over the sphere with $r>R$):

$$\oint_s \vec{E}(r, \theta, \phi) \cdot \hat{n}(r, \theta, \phi) \, ds = \oint_s E(r, \theta, \phi)\, ds = \iiint E(r, \theta, \phi)\, r^2 \sin\theta \, d\theta \, d\phi = E4{\pi}r^2$$

The surface integral depends only on $r$ and is equal to the area of the sphere. $E$ also  by spherical symmetry is idependent of $\theta$ and $\phi$. Spherical symmetry means that if a rotation is made to the system (along $\theta$ or $\phi$ )the field $E$ does **not** change, the rest follows.

Also since

$$\iiint E(r, \theta, \phi)\, r^2 \sin\theta \, d\theta \, d\phi = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$

The result is:

$$E=\frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_04{\pi}r^2}$$

Comment: How can we write the last expression in the first equation?

Comment: @Ome Did the edit answer the question?

Comment: yes, now it is clear. Every books says 'by symmetry argument', but no one writes it clearly. :(

Comment: @Ome, added another edit to make even more clear

Comment: So we have come to know that $E=E(r)$ from a physical argument. Are there any mathematical proof possible?

Comment: @Ome, yes this can be put in [more mathematical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_symmetry) by saying for example the partial derivatives of $E$ wrt to $\phi$ or $\theta$ is zero. However this is the definition of symmetry not necessarily a proof of symmetry. It is part of the definition of a *spherical-symmetric system*.

Comment: Yes, it is not a proof, rather a definition.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Lastly I have found this: http://physnet.org/modules/pdf_modules/m153.pdf

Comment: @NikosM. You can do better than this (I'd actually say the statement you make about spherical symmetry *meaning* that $\mathbf E$ depends only on $r$ isn't quite right).  Notice that in the original specification of the problem, one states that the *charge density* is spherically symmetric.  It is possible to then prove that the corresponding electric field must also be symmetric using its integral expression in terms of the density, but there is something to be proven.  See, for example, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53734/how-do-we-make-symmetry-assumptions-rigorous/53779#53779

Answer (score 1):

You can say this by spherical symmetry argument. All points with given $R$ on a sphere are equivalent.

Now if $E$ depends on $\theta$, then it is different in different directions. So if someone says that $E$ is more at an angle of $30^0$, then your reply would be:
"why not $45^0$ or $70^0$. What is so special about $30^0$."

And that is it. There is nothing special about any direction. Therefore it has to be independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

**Edit:** Spherical symmetry means that all directions are equivalent. Here this is true because the charge distribution is independent of direction ($\theta$ and $\phi$). Therefore we do not have any preferred direction over any other.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on 'spherical symmetry argument'?

Comment: read further. Is it still not clear?

Comment: yes, now it is clear. I had difficulties in understanding the symmetry argument.